# Power BI Embedded report does not update in realtime even though the dataset is pushStreaming

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a streaming+push dataset in power BI. And i push the data through the rest apis. I can see the dashboard in power BI getting updated with the latest data. But the embedded report in my website doesn't seem to update.

How can we achieve this? Is there any additional configuration required when embedding the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI Reports hold a special property that does not allow them to refresh during viewing\editing. This is mainly to allow for presentations & editing, without having to worry about data changes.

However, one can refresh the report view in powerbi.com using the `refresh` button.
In Power BI Embedded, the developer can periodically call `report.refresh()` in the JS SDK to simulate the same action. Time intervals can be synchronized with the known realtime streaming times up to a limit.

Comment: Spot on. For further clarity, the Power BI Javascript SDK allows refreshes every 15 seconds and no sooner as of 2023-05-22.